# How to extract data from table using in sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to use following code to get results from table `companies`. How can I set the value of variable `@strs` to point to a column `name` of my table `companies`.

```
declare @strs nvarchar(max)
set @strs = 'I want to pass table data here' // I want to pass table data here
set @strs = reverse(@strs)
select reverse(@strs) String,
reverse(right(@strs,len(@strs) - charindex(' ',@strs,30))) Description1,
ltrim(reverse(left(@strs,charindex(' ',@strs,30)))) Description2
```

Comment: would you elaborate what do you mean  by table data?

Comment: by table data I mean the values of a field in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you mean ...

```
select @strs = name from companies where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm completely off...you are looking to 'dynamically' select columns base on a variable input.  If this is true, you are looking for dynamic SQL.  This can be a security loop-hole, so it is best if you do some reading on what dynamic SQL entails.  Relatively simple, you are building your SQL statement in a variable and then executing the variable (this is dangerous as I could build a variable as sql code and execute against your server as a SQL injection attack).

```
set @sql = 'select ' + @strs + 'from table'
exec @sql
```

As long as @strs is a list of columns with proper comma''s seperating them, this should work.

I need to ask why you are doing this though...column selection at this level is often best done in the GUI that you are presenting results to your users in...you may want to reconsider why you've decided this is nessacary.

Comment: Actually I have to copy data from table1 to table2. Table1 has field "companyname" which is nvarchar(120). But the table2 has 3 fields each is nvarchar(40)"companyname1", "companyname2","companyname3". I need to split the string in 3 pieces but in a logical way, on the basis of space at the 40th location. 
E.g if a string is "Alufinish Gesellschaft für Verfahrenstechnik u. zur Metalloberflächenbehandlung mbH & C"

it should split like this on the basis of space at 40th location

"Alufinish Gesellschaft für" "Verfahrenstechnik u. zur " "Metalloberflächenbehandlung mbH & C"

Comment: Your question makes quite a bit more sense now...you should edit your question with this information, it's really hard to tell from your question that this is what you are asking.   For a resolution...Is the space always at the 40th and 80th char, or do you need to detect the space as well?  You can use substring and left/right logic to break them into 40 chars (left(field,40) will give the first 40.  The hard part is going to be detecting that space